# Microsoft Access Append Querydef for Memo Field

Tags: ms-access

I am getting an vba error 3271; Invalid property value.  This happens when trying to append a memo field in a querydef.  Any ideas on how to get around this?

Example:

```
public sub TestMemoField
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("AppendRecord")
    qdf.Parameters("@SomeBigText").value = string(1000,"A")
    qdf.Execute
end sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you cannot have a parameter longer than 255 characters ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275116 ).

It is possible to use a recordset, or to use:

```
qdf.SQL="INSERT INTO Sometable (SomeField) Values('" & String(1000, "A") & "')"
```

Answer (score -1):

Um, what are you trying to do? Why are you using parameters? Why not just execute SQL in code, like this:

```
Public Sub TestMemoField
  Dim strSQL As String

  strSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET MyField='" & String(1000,"A") & "'"
  CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

I don't use parameters in saved queries *except* when I need to pull a value from a control on a form to be used in a saved query.

Now, my answer might not be good if your back end is not Jet or if there's something about the actual criteria and structure of your saved query that makes it important to use a saved query instead of simply using on-the-fly SQL. But you've provided virtually no information (including omitting the SQL of the querydef you're executing), so it's rather difficult to supply any kind of helpful answer.

Comment: One reason to use a stored append query is if you are using Access's user level permissions, and need to use the `WITH OWNERACCESS OPTION` to run as a different user.

Comment: Eh? You can still execute it as a user and provide criteria at runtime. There is no reason to define the parameter to allow a user to select a subset of data. Now, if the values to be appended at runtime are what you're defining as parameters, that's different, but you can easily get around that by collecting the data from controls on a form, and defining the form controls as parameters. But for SELECT queries, I see very little reason for ever defining parameters in a saved QueryDef.